# Why I can't append number to my Variable?! in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, append

I having problem with appending or adding numbers to my Integer variable!

I have to view controllers and in the first one I have this codes:

```
    var checkSahafi = Int()

    if sahafi.isSelected == true {
            print("sahafi Selected")
             self.checkSahafi += 1
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondStep", sender: self)

        } else  if safheArayi.isSelected == true {
            print("safheArayi Selected")
            self.checkSahafi += 2
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondStep", sender: self)

        } else if laminet.isSelected == true {
        print("laminet Selected")
            self.checkSahafi += 3
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondStep", sender: self)

    } else if simpichi.isSelected == true {
        print("simpichi Selected")
            self.checkSahafi += 4
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondStep", sender: self)

    }
```

and in the second View Controller I have this method :

```
    let checkNum = firstViewController().checkSahafi

    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

    print("\(checkNum)")
    print("\(checkNum)")
    print("\(checkNum)")
    print("\(checkNum)")

    }
```

But The app Just Print 0
how can I append those numbers?!

**Remember that I used checksahafi.append method too and didn't get the result!**

Comment: where is your data passing code

Comment: no where! I don't have data base in my app

Comment: You can greatly simplify some of this code. Here's what that could look like: https://pastebin.com/EwDbbgq7

Comment: Thanks Alexander The Codes Below Worked For me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are getting value from completely new instance of `FirstViewController` what you need to do is override `prepareForSegue` with your controller and pass value.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
        vc.checkNum = self.checkSahafi
    }
}
```

Now simply change the declaration of `checkNum` in `SecondViewController` like this.

```
var checkNum = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("\(checkNum)")
}
```

Instead of calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in more than once in every if condition simply call it at last after all your if conditions

```
if sahafi.isSelected == true {
    print("sahafi Selected")
    self.checkSahafi += 1
}
else if safheArayi.isSelected == true {
    print("safheArayi Selected")
    self.checkSahafi += 2
}
else if laminet.isSelected == true {
    print("laminet Selected")
    self.checkSahafi += 3
} else if simpichi.isSelected == true {
    print("simpichi Selected")
    self.checkSahafi += 4
}
performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondStep", sender: self)
```

Comment: didn't get the result again can you explain more please?

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Have you override `prepareforSegue` in your firstcontroller also changed the declaration of checkNum in secondViewController if it still not works edit your question with changed code that you have made from my solution

Comment: Thank you So Much It Worked

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Welcome mate :)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for the edit but next time please wait for some minute as of you are continuously trying to edit my answer,So i'm not able to made changes with it also batter if you add formatted code.

Comment: @NiravD - sure bro